# How to find vector $\vec{A}+\vec{B}$ with position vector and displacement vector using different methods

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

When position vector $\vec{A}$ is $\langle 4, -2, 3\rangle$ and displacement vector $\vec{B}$ is from point $Q(0,4,1)$ to point $R(2,3,-2)$

How am I supposed to find vector $\vec{A}+\vec{B}$ using triangle law and parallelogram law?

I believe that $\vec{A}+\vec{B}$ is $\langle 6,-3,0\rangle$, but I'm confused about how I'm supposed to draw vector  $\vec{A}+\vec{B}$ which happens to be $\langle 6, -3, 0\rangle$. Am I supposed to draw a position vector from the origin? I can't seem to figure this out because displacement vector $\vec{B}$ is so far away from $\vec{A}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is right. As far as I know, if you're just trying to draw $\vec A+\vec B$ you can just "move" your vector $\vec B$ so that the tail of $\vec B$ touches the tip of $\vec A$ (Drawing $\vec A$ from the origin). Then $\vec A+\vec B$ is just the resulting vector from the tail of $\vec A$ to the where $\vec B$ ends.

Comment: How do I find  $\vec{A}+\vec{B}$ using triangle law and parallelogram law though?